# Activity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@43cb2348 that was originally bound

Tags: android, memory-leaks, youtube, android-context, android-youtube-api

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413124/activity-has-leaked-serviceconnection-com-google-android-youtube-player-internal) and several other similar questions, and I know the problem and what people are saying is the solution: to use the youtube API, you should use your application context rather than the activity context because of, seemingly, a bug in the youtube API. However, the context must implement OnInitializedListener, and only my activity does that--not my applicationContext.

When I use the line `youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, getApplicationContext());` I get the error `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found android.content.Context, required: 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener'`.

How can I fix this memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `CustomApplication extends Application implements OnInitializedListener`. Then pass the custom application as an argument in method `initialize`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not helping.. I tried this but no luck. error still happen